# extract only alphanumeric token from text string of certain length and negate only letters or only digits in python

Tags: python, regex

text = 'latitude 7400 ws9083r f89'
I am using the below code:

```
match = re.findall(r'(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+',text)
```

and gives me all the tokens in the string:

```
match
Out[]: ['latitude', '7400', 'ws9083r', 'f89']
```

I want to extract 'ws9083r' token from the string i.e. alphanumeric tokens with a length of at least 4.

Comment: Use `r'\b(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)(?=\d*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{4,}\b'`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9NLVbS/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, this part `(?![0-9]*$)` matches a position where what is directly to the right are not only digits till the end of the string, which are all positions except after the characters `f89`

Then this part `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` will match all allowed in the character class, and will match all words in the text.

---

You can assert not only digits and at least 4 characters. Then match at least a single digit.

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})(?![0-9]+\b)[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` Positive lookahead, assert 4 chars
- `(?![0-9]+\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not only digits
- `[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*` Match at least a single digit
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r16G94/1)

```
import re
 
text = 'latitude 7400 ws9083r f89'
match = re.findall(r'\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})(?![0-9]+\b)[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\b', text)
 
print(match)
```

Output

```
['ws9083r']
```